# COALESCE and IFNULL is not returning me NULL record instead of result

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am having a problem with an SQL statement that does not translate the record correctly. The expected result i am supposed to get is

```
Name  tag1 tag2 tag3
Brandon   0   0   0
```

Instead I am getting null values from these 4 columns

This is the sql Statement

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(merchant.merchantname, 'Brandon') AS 'Name',
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transactionamount) from transaction where merchantid = '3' AND transactiondate = '2018-01-29' AND transactionservicetype = 'tag1'),0) AS 'TAG1',
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transactionamount) from transaction where merchantid = '3' AND transactiondate = '2018-01-29' AND transactionservicetype = 'tag2'),0) AS 'TAG2',
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transactionamount) from transaction where merchantid = '3' AND transactiondate = '2018-01-29' AND transactionservicetype = 'tag3'),0) AS 'TAG3' 
FROM merchant RIGHT JOIN transaction ON merchant.merchantid = transaction.merchantid
WHERE merchant.merchantid = '3' AND `transaction`.transactiondate = '2018-01-29'
ORDER BY merchant.merchantid ASC limit 1;
```

Here is sqlfiddle with some data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed1c36a/1

And additionally, is there another way to simplify my SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh?  Just use conditional aggregation.  I think you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(m.merchantname, 'Brandon') AS Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.transactionservicetype = 'tag1' THEN t.transactionamount ELSE 0 END) as tag1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.transactionservicetype = 'tag2' THEN t.transactionamount ELSE 0 END) as tag2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.transactionservicetype = 'tag3' THEN t.transactionamount ELSE 0 END) as tag3
FROM merchant m LEFT JOIN
     transaction t
     ON m.merchantid = t.merchantid AND t.transactiondate = '2018-01-29'
WHERE m.merchantid = 3
GROUP BY m.merchantid
ORDER BY m.merchantid ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases to make the query easier to write and to read.
- The subqueries don't seem to be necessary.
- I'm guessing `merchantid` is a number, so compare it to a number.